# Sum columns of data frame when condition is met

Tags: r, sum

I would like to make a new column that would be the sum of only positive values in existing columns. So in column TotalImportSE3 I would like to obtain sum of of columns SE3-NO1, SE3-DK1, SE3-FI, SE3-SE4 only of positive values, if noone of them are positive sum should be 0.

```
      SE3 - NO1 SE3 - DK1 SE3 - FI SE3 - SE2 SE3 - SE4 TotalImportSE3
 47      1114       666     -225      2716     -3784             NA
 48      1009       671     -151      1491     -2943             NA
 54      1057       711    -1062      1658     -2201             NA
 55      1077       711    -1213      3492     -3015             NA
 94       772       414     -501      2904     -2262             NA
 95      -786      -314     -407     -2368     -2005             NA
```

Output should look like:

```
      SE3 - NO1 SE3 - DK1 SE3 - FI SE3 - SE2 SE3 - SE4 TotalImportSE3
 47      1114       666     -225      2716     -3784             4496
 48      1009       671     -151      1491     -2943             3171
 54      1057       711    -1062      1658     -2201             3426
 55      1077       711    -1213      3492     -3015             5280
 94       772       414     -501      2904     -2262             4090
 95      -786      -314     -407     -2368     -2005             0
```

So far my effort:

```
df1 <- df$`SE3 - NO1`[which(Data$`SE3 - NO1`>0)]
df2 <- df$`SE3 - DK1`[which(Data$`SE3 - DK1`>0)]
```

But it does create two vectors of different lenghts, so it messes up completely.

Comment: I tried to use sum and which function, but so far I managed to extract positive values of separate columns and then sum them, not all columns at the same time.

Comment: you should edit your question to reflect this information. The site is intended to help others and when it looks like you haven't made any effort, people are less inclined to help.

Comment: In your last row, did you mean 314 to be -314?

Comment: Yes indeed it should be -314, edited the question with my newbie effort so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 df$TotalImportSE3=rowSums(df*(df>0))
```

- `df` is name of your dataframe

Comment: Works perfect! However, I don't really understand how * sign works, does it just make a condition for data frame to sum only positive data frame values? Can those be multiple conditons?

Comment: df>0 returns TRUE and FALSE for positive condition (data frame objects greater than zero get TRUE and less than zero get FALSE) ... then by multiplying to  df it returns positive numbers